# How to use datetime column as a time series in Grafana using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, grafana, dashboard, grafana-variable

Hi guys I have a table in Postgres basically storing a door time entry. for example everytime you scan a card to open a door we store the datetime and your id
table format

> CREATE TABLE doorentry(date CHARACTER VARYING(50),id VARCHAR(255))

dataset looks like this

> [{ "id" : "aadams1", "date" : "09-10-2022-14:55:30"},{ "id" : "jjames2", "date" : "09-10-2022-14:55:31"}]

I would like to group the dataset by their timestamp per hour.
I have sort of achieved that with

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(date,0,16) AS byhour, COUNT(id)
FROM doorentry GROUP BY byhour ORDER BY byhour;
```

that looks something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci1iE.png)

Would appreciate any help showing this data as a time series graph/new query to be able to use Grafana  drop down to show data for the last day or hour like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbfD3.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(<TIMESTAMPZ column>, '1h'),
  count(id) AS "count"
FROM doorentry
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(<TIMESTAMPZ column>)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

But you don't have TIMESTAMPZ type in `date`, but VARCHAR. I would recommend to use `TIMESTAMPZ` for `date` column. With VARCHAR you have to convert varchar to timestamp first with SQL, e.g. `TO_TIMESTAMP(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS'`).

See doc for available macros: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/#macros Those macros generate more complex SQL under the hood.

Comment: Thank you, I have actually just set the date table to TIMESTAMP I know it won’t have a time zone but everything works.